# load json file from assets with javascript, Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a javascript cdn and part of the requirements to use this particle.js is to load a json file from the assets directory. This is what my home.html.erb looks like.

```
<div class="fluid-container" id="particles-js">
    <h1>Hello This is a test for particles.js</h1>
    <p>Well does it work?</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function(){
        console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
</script>
```

I also created a particles.json at /app/assets/particles.json

The result in the console is:

particles.js:1539 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/particles.json 404 (Not Found)

Where should I actually put the particles.json file and how should I call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the particles.js from Asset Pipeline, you should use `<%= asset_path 'particles.json' %>` and choose one directory:

- app/assets
- lib/assets
- vendor/assets

Or just put files into a public directory (showing without assets precompile):

- public/yourfolder/particles.json
- http://localhost:3000/yourfolder/particles.json

Comment: I made the mistake of writing `<%= asset_path 'assets/javascript/particles.json' %>` in my example.html.erb. Instead, put your `.json` file in the `app/assets/javascript` folder and then write the code as `<%= asset_path 'particles.json' %>` and it'll find it for you.